The registration token is not a valid FCM registration token (.net)
We are sending the push notifications using Firebase apis. That is getting expired , so we need to upgrade it. We are invoking this from .Net Core 8.0 codebase.
I am trying to use the code step by step provided below. But I am constantly finding this error
https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/push-notification-from-c-sharp-net-to-android-using-fcm-http-v1/
"message": "The registration token is not a valid FCM registration token",
"status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT",
I generated the token using the below code
        string fileName = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "FirebaseServiceAccount\\xyz.json");
        string scopes = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/firebase.messaging";
        var bearertoken = ""; // Bearer Token in this variable

        using (var stream = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
        {
            bearertoken = GoogleCredential
              .FromStream(stream) // Loads key file
              .CreateScoped(scopes) // Gathers scopes requested
              .UnderlyingCredential // Gets the credentials
              .GetAccessTokenForRequestAsync().Result; // Gets the Access Token
        }

Once the token is generated , I am trying to do a POST call to this api
https://fcm.googleapis.com/v1/projects/my-project-name-in-googleconsole/messages:send
Payload:
{
    "message": {
        "token": "ExponentPushToken[xyz.........123]",
        "data": {
            "body": "You have a new Message",
            "title": "New Message",
            "key_1": "Sample Key",
            "key_2": "Sample Key2"
        },
        "notification": {
            "title": "New Message",
            "body": "You have a new Message"
        }
    }
}

I keep getting the error , in-valid registration FCM token. I had 2 queries,

Is this device token in the right format - because in the sample code , I was seeing the device token to be a very long alphanumeric string but in my system, the device token is like this - ExponentPushToken[xyz.........123] (these device tokens work for the legacy FCM code which we were uptill now)

What else could be teh reason behind the error??


Appreciate any suggestions provided to resolve this.

This appears to be documented for C# send messages to multiple devices
